# Creating GUI interface like Linux Install

Tags: linux, bash

I'm looking into creating a menu for a virtual machine image that would allow the user to input certain information such as IP address, gateway, serial number, etc. in a graphical format similar to what the standard Linux OS install looks like... you know, the blue screen with options to select and text fields to input into with 'OK' and 'Back' buttons.

For reference to what I mean about 'standard linux install', the user experience would look like: 
[image]

The user doesn't need access to the underlying Linux (Debian) OS or anything, just the ability to modify the things I want to allow them to.  My goal is to have the GUI interface show up immediately after boot instead of the console prompt to log in (my current image does not have KDE or Gnome installed).

To get my started, I'm looking for someone to tell me what this type of program is called, and possibly some getting started resources.

Thanks!

Comment: Like curses/ncurses?

Comment: Yea, seems to be about the same look/feel I'm going for.  Would I have to automatically boot into a user profile though and the initialize the curses program?

Comment: "the standard Linux OS install" looks pretty different between different distributions, since it is implemented based on quite different frameworks.

Comment: @arkascha added an image so you can see what I mean

Comment: What you describe is not a "type of program". It simply is a program with graphical user interface that is started right after the boot process has finished. Maybe your question is what starts such program? A good approach for that might actually be if you compare it to starting a graphical desktop: first the desktop login manager is fired, which ever. Then one then spawns some other program, typically the graphical user interface. You could do the same, first firing your "configuration step", then firing the "normal" shell or whatever it is you want to execute inside the virtual machine.

Comment: For at least some distros, "menuconfig" is the program ([source](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/scripts/kconfig/mconf.c)).

Comment: As said: these configuration utilities look quite different, depending on _what_ image you load.

Comment: Also look for `Zenity` and `Dialog`. IIRC zenity is by default shipped with older releases of redhat and its clones